# how do i send tweet message with data from my site to twitter account

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, twitter

I need to post a twitter message from my website passing custom message. I used twitter buton but according to requirement i need to send the message after submitting particular form. how do i do this without using twitter button. is there any api for this.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is an API for that, fully documented, on http://dev.twitter.com/

EDIT: Some full .NET sample area available at http://dev.twitter.com/docs/open-source-examples#By_LanguagePlatform

Comment: hi i already checked this one . can u help me out where is the code for that . here in this link it says adding twitter links as buttons in our site. i dont want to add any button or link . i need a solution where message goes to twitter directly after submission of my form. i.e some way to set the account credentials in code and send tweet message

Comment: Man, you must try a little harder. Updated my answer